# Parse Server - afterSave push on specific field change

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, before-save, after-save

I have job collection and it has a field `applicants` which is `Relation` type of class `User`. Now I want to send a push notification to a user when an operation like `AddRelation` or `RemoveRelation` happens on the `applicants` field. Parse Object has following two methods available by which I can understand If i should send a push. these two methods are the following.

```
req.object.dirtyKeys()
req.object.op('applicants')
```

These two functions returns me expected result on `beforeSave` hook. I get an empty result in `afterSave` which is by documentation as expected.

Now my problem is I don't want to send push in `beforeSave` as there might be other validation logic comes up which eventually cancels the operation. I want send push only when the object is saved and the above condition met. Is there anything like to pass data from `beforeSave` to `afterSave`. Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

An easy -- although not too elegant -- way to pass data between `beforeSave` and `afterSave` is to set a property on the object being saved. When you save the object and don't want to pass any info, unset it; else set a value which can be interpreted by `afterSave`. Unfortunately you cannot easily clear the property in `afterSave` because this would cause a new save and thus trigger `beforeSave` again, so the rest of the application should ignore that property...